# How to add animations to presentation made by Latex?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, animations, animate

I am using latex template from overleaf to make my own presentation. In Microsoft Power point, it is very easy to do animations. Could you please let me know how to add animations to the following code. I want the text to first appear (up on pressing enter key in the keyboard) then, the figure, and finally the table should appear. All this need to be done sequentially.

```
   \documentclass[xcolor=table]{beamer}
   \newcommand\hideit[1]{%
 \only<0| handout:1>{\mbox{}}%
 \invisible<0| handout:1>{#1}}
   \mode<presentation> {

 }
  \usetheme{CambridgeUS} 
\usepackage{comment}
 \usepackage{graphicx} 
  \usepackage{booktabs}
 \usepackage{multirow}
   \usepackage{amsmath}
 \newcommand*{\Perm}[2]{{}^{#1}\!P_{#2}}%
 \newcommand*{\Comb}[2]{{}^{#1}C_{#2}}%
\usepackage{amssymb}

    \usepackage{subfig}
   \newcommand{\mathbold}[1]{\text{\textbf{#1}}}
 \makeatletter
     \let\@@magyar@captionfix\relax
  \makeatother
    \begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Results and Discussion(2/2)}
    \begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
         \begin{itemize}
            \item The deploy cost  are relatively low. 

     \item  For the execution cost of Fig.~\ref{gas} shows as the   number      increases, the consumption increases. $\rightarrow$ Exponential increase.
        \end{itemize}

     \end{column}

    \begin{column}{0.6\textwidth}


        \centering 
         \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{figures/thnx.pdf}

       \begin{table}[t]
            \scalebox{0.5}{
             \begin{tabular}{lll}\toprule
    &   GAS  &  Price (ETH) \\ \midrule
  \texttt{Deploy}  &742276             &0.0044537 \\

    \texttt{Recieve} &76981           & 0.0004619   \\
 \bottomrule
   \end{tabular}
  }
        \end{table}

     \end{column}
    \end{columns}

      \end{frame}


  \end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just insert two pauses with the command `\pause`. One after the text, the other after the image.

```
\documentclass[xcolor=table]{beamer}
% \setbeamercovered{dynamic}


\newcommand\hideit[1]{%
\only<0| handout:1>{\mbox{}}%
\invisible<0| handout:1>{#1}}

\mode<presentation> {

}
 \usetheme{CambridgeUS} 
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Allows including images
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand*{\Perm}[2]{{}^{#1}\!P_{#2}}%
\newcommand*{\Comb}[2]{{}^{#1}C_{#2}}%
\usepackage{amssymb}
% \usepackage[ruled,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{subfig}
\newcommand{\mathbold}[1]{\text{\textbf{#1}}}
  \makeatletter
 \let\@@magyar@captionfix\relax
\makeatother

\begin{document}


% \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{example-image-a}


\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Results and Discussion(2/2)}
\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item The deploy cost isrelatively low. 
    \item  For the execution cost of Fig.~\ref {gas} shows  as the number increases, the GAS increases. $\rightarrow$ Exponential increase.
     \end{itemize}
    \end{column}

\pause%first break<--- allows you to take a break, to go on to the next step if you just click
    \begin{column}{0.6\textwidth}
    \centering 
    \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{example-image}
\pause% second break <--- allows you to take a break, to go on to the next step if you just click   
    \begin{table}[t]
    \scalebox{0.5}{
    \begin{tabular}{lll}\toprule
     &   GAS  &  Price (ETH) \\ \midrule
Deploy &742276             &0.0044537 \\

  Receive &76981           & 0.0004619   \\
 \bottomrule

    \end{tabular}
  }
    \end{table}

    \end{column}
    \end{columns}

   \end{frame}


 \end{document}
```